# Using heredoc in zsh aliases

Tags: zsh, alias, here-document

I would like to use heredoc in a `zsh` alias, for example:

```
alias runthing="cd ~; date << HERE
date
HERE"
```

However every time I run this alias, the shell acts as if I have not terminated the heredoc, and displays this:

```
➜  ~ runthing
heredoc>
```

Entering here at the `heredoc>` line finishes the command, although I do not want to do this, thus the alias. I am using oh-my-zsh if that is making any difference.

How do I use heredoc correctly in a zsh alias?

Comment: Hello and welcome! It's unclear _which_ shell are you using. Zsh or Bash? I just tried it with `bash` and it works on my system (well, you have a typo, should be `alias runthing=...` and not `alias=runthing=...` in `bash`).

Comment: @MrShunz, the `heredoc>` secondary prompt is proof that it is `zsh`. I've edited the question to remove the confusing references to bash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The here doc delimiter has to be a delimited line in the alias in `zsh` (it does look like a bug as you do add that delimiter when you press enter), so:

```
alias runthing='cd; date << HERE
date
HERE
'
```

Here, using an alias is wrong though. Consider for instance:

```
echo foo || runthing
```

Because `alias` is just a form of code text substitution (aliases is before all a csh feature, csh had no functions), that becomes

```
echo foo || cd; date...
```

Which means `date` would be run even though `echo` was successful.

You'd better use a function here:

```
runthing() {
  cd && date << EOF
date
EOF
}
```

(of course, it makes little sense to feed a heredoc to `date` given that `date` doesn't read its stdin, I just assume, it was only for the example).

Comment: Yep `date` was just an example! This worked perfectly, thanks!